# How properly mock promise with jest.spyOn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

here is my simplified Class

```
class myClass {
  async function1() {
    try {
      const response = await this.function2()
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
  }


  async function2() {
    try {
      await function3()
      return {status: 200}

    } catch (err) {
      return {status: 400}
    }
  }

}
module.exports = new myClass()
```

So I want to test function1() and mock response from function2()

```
test("test 1", async () => {
  jest.spyOn(myClass, 'function2').mockReturnValue(
    { status: 400 }
  )

  let response = await myClass.function1()
  await expect(response).toEqual(true)
})
```

but function2 still returns status 200. When I run my test in Debug mode - everything works as expected

Comment: You probably wanna use mockResolvedValue({ status: 400 }), as your functions are async and return Promises

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that.. But I tried both.. not working

Comment: well.. seems jest.spyOn not reset after each test
afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
})

Comment: @JohnGlabb Your code for `function` says `return true only if function2 returns 200` and you are mocking `function2` to return `400`. If you mock it to return `200` your test will pass.